# T-SQL syntax causing a loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, t-sql, ssis

The T-SQL statement below is causing one of my SSIS packaged to "hang" at the end of its execution. As in no error messages or feedback, the package simply cannot finish running because of some unseen issue. The two things that come to mind are A) The azure database I'm trying to push to doesn't want to give me update/delete permissions B) There is something wrong with my T-SQL syntax.

I'm going to assume its B because 9 times out of 10 its probably an error on my end rather than a system error. Is there anything in this statement that could cause this loop?

```
--UPDATE
BEGIN
  UPDATE
    REPORTING
  SET
    REPORTING.Supplier = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Supplier,
    REPORTING.Level = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Level,
    REPORTING.Status = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Status,
    REPORTING.[Core Competency Service Provided] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Core Competency Service Provided],
    REPORTING.Location = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Location,
    REPORTING.[Outsourced Process] = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.[Outsourced Process],
    REPORTING.Contact = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Contact,
    REPORTING.Phone = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Phone,
    REPORTING.Email = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.Email
  FROM
    [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL] as REPORTING
    INNER JOIN dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      ON REPORTING.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
  WHERE
    REPORTING.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    AND REPORTING.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL AND dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID IS NOT NULL
END
--DELETE
BEGIN
  DELETE REPORTING
  FROM [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL] as REPORTING
  WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
      SELECT *
      FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP
      WHERE REPORTING.SubtaskID = dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP.SubtaskID
    )
END
```

Comment: Have you checked if locks are blocking the statement? A possibility not mentioned.

Comment: No I have not, thats a good idea though. I'm not sure how to check for locks but I'm sure there are some docs for it

Answer (score 1):

Not a final answer but will be an indication of locks.  Try:

```
BEGIN
  DELETE top(10) REPORTING
  FROM [AZURE_REPORTING].[Reporting_Warehouse].[dbo].[SupplierQuality_ASL] as REPORTING
  WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM dbo.SupplierQuality_ASL_TEMP as TEMP
                     WHERE REPORTING.SubtaskID = TEMP.SubtaskID
                   )
END
```

Comment: I tried this but the the package hung again in the same spot. This is curious because I've just ran each individual statement in my query against my database manually and they all finished in a timely manner. This would lead me to believe I've configured something incorrectly in SSIS

Comment: Unless this is how OLE DB commands work then I wouldn't think so. I'll try breaking the statements into 3 different commands and see if that does anything.

Comment: @NoOrangeJuice I meant to write `Delete top(10)`

Comment: Turn out moving the command out of a data flow task and into an execute sql task solved my problem. Thanks for your help